Which sigma-ideals in a sigma-algebra are contained in an ideal of null sets?
Let $X$ be a Polish space and $\mathcal{B}(X)$ be the $\sigma$-algebra of Borel subsets of $X$. Given a Borel probability measure $\mu$ on $X$, we write $\mathcal{N}(\mu) := \{ B \in \mathcal{B}(X) : \mu(B)=0\}$ for the $\sigma$-ideal of $\mu$-nullsets.
Question: Let $\mathcal{I} \subseteq{B}(X)$ be a given $\sigma$-ideal. Are there sufficient/necessary conditions on $\mathcal{I}$ such that $\mathcal{I}$ is contained in the null ideal of a Borel probability measure?
What I know so far:

There is already a thread on the question when a $\sigma$-ideal IS the ideal of nullsets of a Borel probability measure, see:  Which sigma-ideals in a sigma-algebra are ideals of null sets? However, I was not able to derive a useful answer to my question from this thread.

There are $\sigma$-ideals that are not the null-ideal of a probability measure, but contained in such an ideal: For example, $\mathcal{I} : = \{ B \subset [0,1] : B \text{ is countable}\}$. Then $\mathcal{I} \subseteq \mathcal{B}([0,1])$ is not the $\sigma$-ideal of a Borel probability measure because $\mathcal{B}([0,1])/\mathcal{I}$ does not satisfy the countable chain condition, whereas $\mathcal{B}([0,1])/\mathcal{N}(\mu)$ does for every Borel probability measure $\mu$. However, $\mathcal{I}$ is contained in the null-ideal of the Lebesgue measure.

Not every propper $\sigma$-ideal is contained in a null-ideal: For example, consider the $\sigma$-ideal $\mathcal{I} := \{ B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}): \text{ there is a $\sigma$-compact $C$ s.t. } B \subseteq C \}$. As $\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}$ is not $\sigma$-compact, this is a propper ideal. Assume for the sake of contradiction that $\mathcal{I} \subseteq \mathcal{N}(\mu)$ for some probability measure $\mu$. Then $\mu$ vanishes on all compact sets and by inner regularity $\mu=0$.


Any reference or ideas would be greatly appreciated!
